# Slick and leftjoin : wrong type on result tuple

Tags: slick

I'm trying to do a left join with Slick.

I have two case classes (Book and Author) and 2 tables

If I do this :

```
(for {
       (book, author) <- Books leftJoin Authors on (_.authorId === _.id)
     } yield (book, author.?)
).list
```

The result is a List[Book, Option[Authors.type]] and I need a List[Book, Option[Author]]

Do you know why I get the wrong type with my query?

Note : my Authors object links well with the Author case class:

```
object Authors extends Table[Author]("author"){...}
```

Thanks :)

Loïc

Comment: also see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scalaquery/be5750vbM3U

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but I don't know if it's the right solution.

I retrieve the authors optional columns and then I use the map function on my results to create the (Book, Author) tuple objects.

```
val query = for {
(book, author) <- Books leftJoin Companies on (_.authorId === _.id)
} yield (book, author.id.?, author.name.?)

val result = query.list.map(row => (row._1, row._2.map(value => Author(Option(value), row._3.get))))
```